# Problems with autoinstall

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity, curtin, autoinstall

I'm trying out the new [autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference) method that supersedes the classical debian installer.

I've built the following configs:

user-data:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
  reporting:
    hook:
      type: webhook
      endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:8000
      level: INFO
  storage:
    version: 1
    config:

      - id: sda
        type: disk
        ptable: gpt
        path: /dev/vda
        grub_device: 1
        wipe: superblock
      - id: sda1
        type: partition
        size: 8GB
        device: sda

      - id: sdb
        type: disk
        ptable: gpt
        path: /dev/vdb
        wipe: superblock
      - id: sdb1
        type: partition
        size: 8GB
        device: sdb

      - id: bios_boot_partition
        type: partition
        size: 1MB
        device: sda
        flag: bios_grub
      - id: mddevice
        name: md0
        type: raid
        raidlevel: 1
        devices:
          - sda1
          - sdb1
      - id: md_root
        type: format
        fstype: ext4
        volume: mddevice

      - id: md_mount
        type: mount
        path: /
        device: md_root
```

When I serve this config over http as suggested in this [article](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart), I can install the system just fine. However, when I put this config on my dvd, I run into errors later on in the install. For reference, here is my txt.cfg:

```
default live
label live
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append   initrd=/casper/initrd quiet ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/customer/inst/ ---
```

my installation fails after the partitioning stage. It's hard to say what's going on, but this is what I see:

- the cdrom unmount fails early in the installation

(please bare with me for posting a screenshot, but I suppose it is the most effective:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fighting similar problems now. This new system is difficult to understand and debug.

As for the exact error you mention, I've seen people claim multiple causes and I've even run in to it myself. I suggest using the installer's second tty (Ctrl + Alt + F2) and reading the logs at /var/log and /target/var/log. In my case, the problem was that the squashfs did not have my repository signing key in it, so apt could not verify the signature for the repos on the install image.

The cd unmount thing seems to be a bug. I get it all the time, even for successful installations.